# Filter event reports by facilitator

Tags: civievent, civireport

Currently if I want to collate a report on events facilitated by a particular individual (or, say, run by a partner organisation, or any contact with a custom role), I have to go to each event from their contact record, or add each event title to the event 'is one of' filter - it's not possible to filter the event participant list report by a facilitator without limiting the data to that facilitator, and the other event reports (e.g. event summary) can't be filtered by an individual.

Is it possible to build a report to filter in this way? i.e. for a list of events filtered by one contact record, provide data on all event participants.

(I had considered just adding the facilitator as a custom contact reference field, but unfortunately that only allows me to add one contact per field, and there's sometimes more than one facilitator per event.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a client with a similar issue.  They resolved it by not adding a facilitator to any events they didn't facilitate.

Assuming that's not a workable workaround for you - it IS possible to generate reports like you're describing, but you'd need to either a) code it (or find someone to code it), or b) use an (often pricey) third-party reporting tool.  Come join us at https://chat.civicrm.org if you'd like to discuss custom reporting options - either doing it yourself or finding someone to do them.

Comment: I figured I'd have to build something, but as I've not gotten into coding new reports and have a slightly shaky grasp of the MySQL side of things, I didn't want to start digging into that process only to find that it wasn't possible at all - if it's at least theoretically possible, I'll bring it to the chat site to see if I can get some pointers.

Comment: Re: your first point - it's unlikely that our facilitators won't also be attendees of other events, but if it was, I don't see how I get information about the other attendees of events they're facilitating (I can get all the events they facilitate, but then have to go into each event to collect information about event participants)

Comment: You're right - I'm misremembering.  I've since moved companies, so I can't look at my old notes to see how it was resolved.  Sorry!

Comment: No problem - I'll raise it in the chat site when I get a chance